# Custom module importing

Tags: python, module, package

```
- AWS/
        -__init__.py
        - file2/
            - _init_.py 
            - test1.py
        - random/
            - test.py



How can I import test1.py in test.py ?
```

tried
1. from ..file2 import test1
2. from file2 import test1

Its giving me
for 1 ----> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

for 2 --->ImportError: No module named file2

Answer (score 0):

[You can find a great answer of imports here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/10129383).

Specifically:

> Scripts can't import relative
>
> What you probably did is you tried to run moduleX or the like from the
> command line. When you did this, its name was set to **main**, which
> means that relative imports within it will fail, because its name does
> not reveal that it is in a package. Note that this will also happen if
> you run Python from the same directory where a module is, and then try
> to import that module, because, as described above, Python will find
> the module in the current directory "too early" without realizing **it
> is part of a package.**
>
> Also remember that when you run the interactive interpreter, the
> "name" of that interactive session is always **main**. Thus you cannot
> do relative imports directly from an interactive session. Relative
> imports are only for use within module files.
>
> Two solutions:
>
> If you really do want to run moduleX directly, but you still want it
> to be considered part of a package, you can do python -m
> package.subpackage1.moduleX. The -m tells Python to load it as a
> module, not as the top-level script.
>
> Or perhaps you don't actually want to run moduleX, you just want to
> run some other script, say myfile.py, that uses functions inside
> moduleX. If that is the case, put myfile.py somewhere else – not
> inside the package directory – and run it. If inside myfile.py you do
> things like from package.moduleA import spam, it will work fine.

Where you can substitute moduleX for your random test.py.

With the same structure as you, and working in the parent dir of the AWS folder, with test.py containing:

```
from ..file2 import test1


print("Hello from test.py")
```

and test1.py:

```
print("I'm test1.py")
```

`python -m AWS.random.test` produces:

```
I'm test1.py
Hello from test.py
```

As the linked answer points out, your script is part of the package therefore will need to be ran as part of the package or moved out.